# "Encountering Persistent 'Tag Mismatch' Error During App Build Process - Seeking Assistance to Resolve"

Tags: android, gradle

Problem Description:
For the past seven days, I've been encountering a persistent issue while attempting to build my app. The problem arises during the build process, where I consistently receive a "tag mismatch" error. This error disrupts the download of necessary files (typically dependencies or libraries) required for the app's build process. Despite numerous attempts to address this issue, I haven't found a solution yet.

Challenges Faced:

Error Nature: The "tag mismatch" error occurs consistently during the download phase of the build process.
Persistence: The problem has persisted for a week, hampering progress on the app development.
Troubleshooting Efforts: I've tried various troubleshooting steps but have not been successful in resolving the issue.
Details of Attempts:

Network and Connectivity: Ensured stable internet connectivity without interruptions, and checked proxy settings in case they were affecting downloads.
Cache Clearance: Cleared cache for build tools (e.g., Gradle, npm) and retried the build command to eliminate cached file issues.
Dependency Management: Reviewed project's dependency management files (e.g., build.gradle, package.json) for any incorrect or outdated references to dependencies.
Tool Versions: Ensured usage of the latest versions of build tools, plugins, and dependencies to address potential compatibility issues.
Repository Sources: Attempted to switch repository sources for dependencies, trying alternatives to the current repository (e.g., moving from JCenter to Maven Central).
Request for Assistance:
I'm seeking guidance or support in resolving this "tag mismatch" error during the app build process. If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights into potential solutions, I would greatly appreciate any advice or assistance.

Additional Notes:

The error seems to halt the build process, preventing the successful completion of the app's compilation.
I'm open to trying new approaches or steps suggested by others to overcome this persistent issue.

```
 What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download gradle-7.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.2.1/gradle-7.2.1.jar'.
         > Tag mismatch!
   > Could not download kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.8.0-gradle71.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.8.0/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.8.0-gradle71.jar'.
         > Tag mismatch!
   > Could not download builder-7.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:7.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/7.2.1/builder-7.2.1.jar'.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.